# How to access a cell and add it to another dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iterable

my question is: How to access a cell and add it to another dataframe in Pandas
This is my dataframe:

```
new = marker_df.describe() 
new
```

> ```
> acceleration  seconds seconds_diff    revolutions_per_second
> count 3.000000    3.000000    2.000000    2.000000
> mean  10116.666667    0.398737    0.301705    3.314497
> std   245.980352  0.301705    0.000447    0.004906
> min   9833.000000 0.096926    0.301389    3.311027
> 25%   10039.500000    0.247937    0.301547    3.312762
> 50%   10246.000000    0.398947    0.301705    3.314497
> 75%   10258.500000    0.549642    0.301863    3.316231
> max   10271.000000    0.700337    0.302021    3.317966
> ```

and here another dataframe:

```
first_df = pd.DataFrame()
```

And now I want to access a cell from `new` and add it to `first_df`

I did this:

```
acc = new.at["count",'acceleration']
first_df = first_df.join(float(acc))
first_df
```

And got this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

now help me please! :)

Comment: Do you need `first_df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[acc]})` ?

Comment: @jezrael, yup. that works too, thanksss

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
first_df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[acc]})
```